# jQuery Infinite Scroll with JSONP Request

Tags: jquery, jsonp, instagram, infinite-scroll

I have been trying infinite scroll for my own website. It is working fine if i give same website url. But if i give the api.instagram.com instead, then it is not requesting jsonp request and the request is unsuccessful.

Please suggest me that how do i implement infinite scroll with jsonp request,

Below is my piece of code,

```
$('.thumbnails').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : "a#next:last",            
    nextSelector : "a#next:last",   
    contentSelector : ".thumbnails",
    itemSelector    : ".thumbnails",
    dataType: 'json'
});     



navSelctor is <a id="next" href="https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tamil/media/recent?callback=jQuery18304228946652839459_1357811552825&client_id=f34d9190c452476d931b813c7bc5e368&max_tag_id=1357828120918&access_token=73b038d4a22848c295dc813b37720ada&_=1357811765921">more</a>

Below is Content Selector

<ul class="thumbnails">
    <div style="text-align:center;display:none;" id="no_photo"> No photos found! </div> 
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you can provide the code how you refactored to use the Infinitescroll with jsonp that will be of big help for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Paul Irish's [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) plugin, it supports loading JSON data (using `$.ajax()` with `dataType: 'json'`) but not JSONP. You'll need to patch it to support JSONP (which may not be too difficult) or use a different plugin.

Comment: Yes.. I checked with the plugin js and i didnt find any $.ajax() to patch it for jsonp support. Is there any other plugin which support jsonp request?

Comment: To patch the plugin, I'd adapt the [`case 'json':`](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/60dea24f18bc134b8fba5a3e23367d8e11f7e38d/jquery.infinitescroll.js#L579) section for JSONP (plus some other bits; search for "dataType"). I don't know any other infinite scroll plugins; any plugin I suggest will come from a Google search.

Comment: Mistakenly, i was using this plugin (http://jscroll.com/) which doesnt have an option like you mentioned. Now i have changed "Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll plugin" and as you suggested, i have changed the dataType to jsonp. Working fine now. Thanks for your great support.

Comment: @Yadheendran , can you please provide me some code how you changed the Paul Irish code to get data from jsonP instead of regular page numbers

Comment: Just find the "case 'json'" (line no: 579). Then i have changed the line from "dataType: 'json" to dataType: 'jsonp' to enable jsonp support.